# Random records in Oracle table based on conditions

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a Oracle table with the following columns

Table Structure

[image: Table Structure]

In a query I need to return all the records with CPER>=40 which is trivial. However, apart from CPER>=40 I need to list 5 random records for each CPID. 
I have attached a sample list of records. However, in my table I have around 50,000 records. 
Appreciate if you can help.

Comment: SQL Server or Oracle?

Comment: Sorry Oracle Table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle solution:

```
with CTE as
(
select t1.*, 
       row_number() over(order by DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE) as rn -- random order assigned
from MyTable t1
where CPID <40
)
select *
from CTE
where rn <=5 -- pick 5 at random

union all
select t2.*, null
from my_table t2
where CPID >= 40
```

SQL Server:

```
with CTE as
(
select t1.*, 
       row_number() over(order by newid()) as rn -- random order assigned
from MyTable t1
where CPID <40
)
select *
from CTE
where rn <=5 -- pick 5 at random

union all
select t2.*, null
from my_table t2
where CPID >= 40
```

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I am looking for all records with CPER>=40 and random 5 records per CPID where CPER<40.

Comment: @FirstAider Change the CTE to get the randoms, then union all the over 40s, ensuring you add a null column, or explicitly define the columns in the CTE

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this...

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT CID,
               CVAL,
               CPID,
               CPER,
               Row_number() OVER (partition BY CPID ORDER BY CPID ASC ) AS RN
        FROM   Table) tmp
WHERE  CPER>=40 OR pids <= 5
```

However, this is not random.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want five *additional* random records, you can do:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by cpid,
                                             (case when cper >= 40 then 1 else 2 end)
                                order by dbms_random.value
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 5 or cper >= 40;
```

The `row_number()` is enumerating the rows for each `cpid` in two groups -- based on the `cper` value.  The outer `where` is taking all `cper` values in the range you want as well as five from the other group.